# SQL count occurrences in window

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have user logins by date. My requirement is to track the number of users that have been logged in during the past 90 days window.

I am new to both SQL in general and Teradata specifically and I can't get the window functionality to work as I need.

I need the following result, where ACTIVE is a count of the unique USER_IDs that appear in the previous 90 day window the DATE.

```
DATES        ACTIVE_IN_WINDOW
12/06/2018     20
13/06/2018     45                 
14/06/2018     65 
15/06/2018     73 
17/06/2018     24      
18/06/2018     87  
19/06/2018     34
20/06/2018     51
```

Currently my script is as follows.

It is this line here that I cant get right

```
COUNT ( USER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY EVT_DT ROWS BETWEEN 90 PRECEDING AND  0 FOLLOWING)
```

I suspect I need a different set of functions to make this work.

```
SELECT    b.DATES , a.ACTIVE_IN_WINDOW

FROM    

(
        SELECT 

        CAST(CALENDAR_DATE AS DATE) AS DATES FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR

        WHERE DATES BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, - 10)  AND CURRENT_DATE
) b

LEFT JOIN

(
        SELECT    USER_ID   , EVT_DT 

        , COUNT ( USER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY EVT_DT ROWS BETWEEN 90 PRECEDING AND  0 FOLLOWING) AS ACTIVE_IN_WINDOW

        FROM ENV0.R_ONBOARDING
) a

ON a.EVT_DT = b.DATES

ORDER BY b.DATES
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: `ORDER BY EVT_DT ROWS BETWEEN 90 PRECEDING AND  0 FOLLOWING)` is the part where the logic fails - unless someone logs in every day, there is no correlation between the number of rows you skip back over and the number of days they logged in for. Skipping back over the last 90 rows might see you counting login dates 270 days ago if they only log in once every 3 days. 
In some other DBMS this can be overcome with `OVER(order by event_dt RANGE BETWEEN SYSDATE-90 AND SYSDATE)` or similar. Teradata lacks this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is similar to Gordon', but a *non-equi-Join* instead of a *Correlated Scalar Subquery* is usually more efficient on Teradata:

```
SELECT b.DATES , Count(DISTINCT USER_ID)
FROM
 (
   SELECT CALENDAR_DATE AS DATES 
   FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR
   WHERE DATES BETWEEN Add_Months(Current_Date, - 10)  AND Current_Date
 ) b
LEFT JOIN
 ( -- apply DISTINCT before aggregation to reduce intermediate spool
   SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, EVT_DT
   FROM ENV0.R_ONBOARDING
 ) AS a
ON a.EVT_DT BETWEEN Add_Months(b.DATES,-3) AND b.DATES
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Of course this will require a large spool and much CPU.

Edit:

Switching to weeks reduces the overhead, I'm using dates instead of week numbers (it's easier to modify for other ranges):

```
SELECT b.Week , Count(DISTINCT USER_ID) 
FROM
 ( -- Return only Mondays instead of DISTINCT over all days 
   SELECT calendar_date AS Week
   FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR 
   WHERE CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN Add_Months(Current_Date, -9) AND Current_Date
     AND day_of_week = 2 -- 2 = Monday
 ) b 
LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID,
     -- td_monday returns the previous Monday, but we need the following monday
     -- covers the previous Tuesday up to the current Monday
            Td_Monday(EVT_DT+6) AS PERIOD_WEEK
   FROM ENV0.R_ONBOARDING
   -- You should add another condition to limit the actually covered date range, e.g.
   -- where EVT_DT BETWEEN Add_Months(b.DATES,-13) AND b.DATES
 ) AS a 
ON a.PERIOD_WEEK BETWEEN b.Week-(12*7) AND b.Week 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1
```

Explain should duplicate the calendar as preparation for the product join, if not you might need to materialize the dates in a Volatile Table. Better don't use `sys_calendar`, there are no statistics, e.g. optimizer doesn't know about how many days per week/month/year, etc. Check your system, there should be a calendar table designed for you company needs (with stats on all columns)

Comment: Solved. Thanks. It performs well on 2 mill rows, 60k users at 30GB spool space.

Comment: Having performance issues and trying to change from day level to month level. Is there a way in Teradata to operate on the month level without changing to char? Defining my 3 month window will not work with char.  

`TO_CHAR(CALENDAR_DATE, 'Mon') AS DATES`

`ON a.EVT_DT BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(b.DATES,-3) AND b.DATES` <- not working with TO_CHAR

Comment: When you simply apply TO_CHAR you get multiple rows per month, you need to reduce it to one per month (and similar for ENV0.R_ONBOARDING). What defines *month level*, calendar months (Dec 1-31) or one month back from today (Nov 12 - Dec 11)?

Comment: Btw, weeks would probably be simpler, either calendar weeks or 7 days...

Comment: Changing to week level with window of 12 weeks. It looks fine at first but is overestimating toward the end. 
`SELECT b.DATES , Count(DISTINCT USER_ID)
FROM
 (
SELECT DISTINCT TD_SYSFNLIB.WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (CALENDAR_DATE, 'ISO') AS WEEK
FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR
WHERE CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, - 9)  AND CURRENT_DATE
 ) b
LEFT JOIN
   SELECT DISTINCT USER_ID, TD_SYSFNLIB.WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (a.EVT_DT, 'ISO') AS  PERIOD_WEEK
   FROM ENV0.R_ONBOARDING
 ) AS a
ON a.PERIOD_WEEK BETWEEN (b.WEEK -12) AND b.WEEK
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1`

Comment: What do you mean by *overestimating toward the end*? Btw, `BETWEEN (b.WEEK -12) AND b.WEEK` are *13* weeks

Comment: In my total period of 9 months, the weekly level is in line with the first attempt at daily level on on the earliest part of the window. As we slide toward the end of the 9 month total period, it overestimates by 10 % in the window compared to the daily level.

Comment: `BETWEEN (b.WEEK -12) AND b.WEEK` covers exactly 90 days, but `EVT_DT BETWEEN Add_Months(b.DATES,-3) AND b.DATES` covers up to 93 days, this might cause the difference. Compare to `EVT_DT BETWEEN b.DATES-90) AND b.DATES`

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not too big, a subquery might be the simplest method:

```
SELECT c.dte,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.USER_ID)
        FROM ENV0.R_ONBOARDING o
        WHERE o.EVT_DT > ADD_MONTHS(dte, -3) AND
              o.EVT_DT <= dte
       ) as three_month_count
FROM (SELECT CAST(CALENDAR_DATE AS DATE) AS dte
      FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR
      WHERE CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, - 10)  AND CURRENT_DATE
     ) c;
```

You might want to start on a shorter timeframe then 3 months to see how the query performs.